# The 'Hangman' game python code testing

Tags: python, loops

I have written this code for the Hangman game in which the opponent is the computer. But I keep getting errors that I do not know how to solve. please take a look for me. For example, my current error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python code\hangmangame_test.py", line 112, in <module>
    hangman(a)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python code\hangmangame_test.py", line 91, in hangman
    if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed) == "True":
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python code\hangmangame_test.py", line 12, in isWordGuessed
    if i in lettersGuessed:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

---

```
import string
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    new = ""
    for i in secretWord:
        if i in lettersGuessed:
            new += i
            if new == secretWord:
                return True
        else:
            return False

def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    result = list(secretWord)
    for i in result:
        if i not in lettersGuessed:
            result[result.index(i)] = " _ "
    transtring = ''.join(result)
    return transtring


def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    Alletters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = list(Alletters)
    for i in lettersGuessed:
        if i in result:
            result.remove(i)
    transtring = ''.join(result)
    return transtring



def hangman(secretWord):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    * At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
      letters the secretWord contains.

    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.

    * The user should receive feedback immediately after each guess 
      about whether their guess appears in the computers word.

    * After each round, you should also display to the user the 
      partially guessed word so far, as well as letters that the 
      user has not yet guessed.

    Follows the other limitations detailed in the problem write-up.
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    print("Welcome to the Hangman game!")
    print('\n')
    print("My word has " + str(len(secretWord)) + " letters!")
    guesses = 8      # No. of guesses
    lettersGuessed = []   # Creating empty list
    Alletters = string.ascii_lowercase    # String containing all the lowercase letters
    while guesses > 0:    # Game starts
        print("You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left!")
        print("Available letters: " + str(Alletters))
        letters = input("Please guess a letter: ")
        if type(letters) != str:
            print("Invalid input! please enter one letter!")
        else:
            letterslower = letters.lower()     # Transfering input into lowercase
            lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)  # Inserting inputs into a list
            if letterslower not in Alletters:
                print("Opps! you have already guessed that letter: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            else:
                if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed) == "True":
                    print("Congradualation! you won!")
                else:
                    print("Good guess: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                    guesses -= 1
                    Alletters = getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
    print("You have ran out of guess, the word is " + str(secretWord))







# a = "puck"
# b = ["f", "a", "c", "t"]
# print(isWordGuessed(a, b))
# print(getGuessedWord(a, b))
# print(getAvailableLetters(b))

a = "junior"
hangman(a)
```

Comment: From our rules: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself". Simply saying "I'm getting errors, please fix" is not enough.

Comment: `lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)` doesn't do what you think - `list.append` is **in-place**, it modifies the list and returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is caused by this line:

```
lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)
```

The `append` method works in-place, and returns `None`, so your list becomes a `NoneType` because you set it equal to that call. Just get rid of the assignment:

```
lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)
```

Comment: ahha, thx man. Now I am running this code, the guesses just keep decreasing, even if I guess right!!!

Comment: @CharlesLi I'm sure you're aware that that needs to be a separate question. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

line 87 : `lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)` instead of `lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)`

Append does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
lettersGuessed = lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)
```

you are assigning `None` to `lettersGuessed`, because that is what `append` returns.

Just use:

```
lettersGuessed.append(letterslower)
```